# How to find if some part of code is a declaration (when takes effect)? How practically useful is it to know that?

Tags: perl

I'm getting acquainted with perl. I've been using one-liners for some time, now I want to understand longer programs.

I'm reading man pages, completed perl, perlintro, perlsyn. After finding out there is `man strict` I've got very impressed with perl documentation.

In `perlsyn` 'Declarations':

> A declaration can be put anywhere a statement can, but has no effect
> on the execution of the primary sequence of statements: declarations
> all take effect at compile time.

However I could not find how to distinguish a declaration. As I've understood a call to a function could be a statement and also a declaration, e.g. `use VERSION` is many times mentioned in man pages as a `declaration`. How useful is it to know which line is a declaration and which is not?

Added (and title edited, 'line' replaced):

I realised it might be important to know if something is processed during compilation. Answer by @ikegami calls `use` a `directive`, however more important is how it is processed:

> Because "use" takes effect at compile time, it doesn't respect the ordinary flow control of the code being compiled.  In particular, putting a "use" inside the false branch of a conditional doesn't prevent it from being processed.

Any general way to know if some part of code takes effect during compilation?

Comment: You've added a new question, "Any general way to know if some part of code takes effect during compilation?" Well, all code does. Not much point to having code the compiler ignores. Unless you mean evaluated? `use`d modules and code in `BEGIN` blocks are evaluated as soon as they are compiled. But that has nothing to do with declarations.

Comment: @ikegami. you write "all code does". I've only used language from `perlfunc` man page, from part I've quoted in the question. The question indeed looks as new one, initially I've understood man pages as `Declarations` take effect during compilation, but you wrote `use` is not a declaration. Again about raising a bug issue for docs (including clarification about `evaluated`): is it appropriate in your opinion? TIA

Comment: Sure the wording could be more precise, but it's not wrong, and it unambiguously communicates what it wants to communicate.

Answer (score 3):

Declarations give the compiler information about the thing you are declaring.

- You can declare a sub.

  ```perl
  sub foo;        # Declares a sub that has neither a prototype nor a signature.
  sub bar($);     # Declares a sub with a prototype
  sub baz( $x );  # Declares a sub with a signature
  sub qux { }     # Defining a sub also declares it.
  ```

  In Perl, you don't normally need to declare a sub other than when defining it. A couple of examples where it would be needed:

  - To allow a parenthesis-less sub call to sub that hasn't been defined yet.

    ```perl
    sub f;

    f;

    sub f {
       ...
    }
    ```
  - For a recursive sub that has a prototype or signature.

    ```perl
    sub g($);

    sub g($) {
       ...
       ... g($x) ...
       ...
    }
    ```
- You can declare a variable.

  Unlike subs, declaring a variable also creates it.

  ```perl
  my $x;     # Lexically-scoped variable.
  state $x;  # Lexically-scoped persitent variable.
  our $x;    # Lexically-scoped alias to a package variable.
  ```

> How useful is it to know which line is a declaration and which is not?

Knowing what a declaration does allows you to use it when needed.

---

The documentation for `use VERSION;` does call it a declaration, but that would be a different sense of the word. "Directive" would be a better word here. A directive is loose term for something that instructs a compiler how to behave. `use VERSION;` does not declare anything, but directs the compiler to perform a version check, and it tells it what "version of the language" to use.

It's not a format concept. What qualifies as a directive is subjective, so

> How useful is it to know which line is a <strike>declaration</strike> directive and which is not?

It's not.

(Also, "line"? With very few exceptions, Perl doesn't care about lines.)

Comment: Updated. ______

Comment: Thanks. `line` was not correct, edited the title. Also please see `Added` section. `use` - directive: is it worth to try to improve the docs via raising the issue upstream?